# Need help... Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/64 bit Lenovo machine V310 Freezes frequently. If I play video in browser machine will get stuck within 15-20 minutes!

Tags: lenovo, freeze

My Ubuntu **16.04LTS** machine gets freeze frequently the make & model is **Lenovo - V310**. It happens all the time but if I'm playing a video online in browser them machine will get freeze within 15-20 minutes even if I stopped playing the video. I tried with different browsers but it happens with all. Your help will be appreciated.

**Following are my system test report.**

Audio tests         passed

```
☑   audio/alsa_record_playback_external passed
☑   audio/alsa_record_playback_internal passed
☑   audio/alsa_record_playback_usb  passed
☑   audio/list_devices  passed
☑   audio/playback_auto passed
☑   audio/playback_headphones   passed
```

Benchmarks tests            passed

```
☑   benchmarks/disk/hdparm-cache-read_sda   passed
☑   benchmarks/disk/hdparm-read_sda passed
```

Bluetooth tests         passed

```
☑   bluetooth/detect-output passed
```

CPU tests           passed

```
☑   cpu/clocktest   passed
☑   cpu/offlining_test  passed
☑   cpu/topology    passed
```

Camera tests            passed

```
☑   camera/detect   passed
☑   camera/display  passed
☑   camera/still    passed
```

Disk tests          passed

```
☑   disk/detect passed
```

Ethernet Device tests           skipped

```
☐   ethernet/detect not supported
```

ExpressCard tests           passed

```
☑   expresscard/verification    passed
```

Firewire disk tests         failed

```
☒   firewire/insert failed
☐   firewire/remove not supported
☐   firewire/storage-test   not supported
```

Graphics tests          passed

```
☑   Test Compiz support for PCI ID 0x5916   passed
☑   Test X driver/version for PCI ID 0x5916 passed
☑   Test that PCI ID 0x5916 meets minimum resolution requirement    passed
☑   Test default resolution for PCI ID 0x5916   passed
☑   Test that VESA drivers are not in use   passed
```

Hotkey tests            passed

```
☑   keys/battery-info   passed
☑   keys/brightness passed
☑   keys/media-control  passed
☑   keys/mute   passed
☑   keys/sleep  passed
☑   keys/super  passed
☑   keys/volume passed
☑   keys/wireless   passed
```

Informational tests         passed

```
☑   codecs_attachment   passed
☑   Attach a copy of /proc/cpuinfo  passed
☑   Attach a copy of /var/log/dmesg passed
☑   Attach a copy of /sys/class/dmi/id/*    passed
☑   Attach a copy of of the output of dmidecode passed
☑   efi_attachment  passed
☑   lshw_attachment passed
☑   Attach a list of currently running kernel modules   passed
☑   Attach a list of PCI devices    passed
☑   Attach the contents of modprobe configuration files passed
☑   Attach the contents of /etc/modules passed
☑   Attach sysctl configuration files.  passed
☑   Attach detailed sysfs property output from udev passed
☑   Attach hardware database (udev) passed
```

Input Devices tests         passed

```
☑   input/keyboard  passed
☑   input/mouse passed
```

Media Card tests            failed

```
☒   mediacard/cf-insert failed
☐   mediacard/cf-remove not supported
☐   mediacard/cf-storage    not supported
☒   mediacard/mmc-insert    failed
☐   mediacard/mmc-remove    not supported
☐   mediacard/mmc-storage   not supported
☒   mediacard/sd-insert failed
☐   mediacard/sd-remove not supported
☐   mediacard/sd-storage    not supported
☒   mediacard/sdhc-insert   failed
☐   mediacard/sdhc-remove   not supported
☐   mediacard/sdhc-storage  not supported
```

Miscellaneous tests         passed

```
☑   miscellanea/is_laptop   passed
☑   miscellanea/submission-resources    passed
```

Optical Drive tests         passed

```
☑   optical/detect  passed
☑   optical/read_sr0    passed
```

Power Management tests          passed

```
☑   power-management/rtc    passed
```

Suspend tests           failed

```
☒   mediacard/cf-insert-after-suspend   failed
☐   mediacard/cf-remove-after-suspend   not supported
☐   mediacard/cf-storage-after-suspend  not supported
☑   suspend/audio_after_suspend passed
☑   suspend/audio_before_suspend    passed
☑   suspend/bluetooth_detect_after_suspend  passed
☑   suspend/memory_after_suspend    passed
☑   suspend/memory_before_suspend   passed
☒   suspend/mmc-insert-after-suspend    failed
☐   suspend/mmc-remove-after-suspend    not supported
☐   suspend/mmc-storage-after-suspend   not supported
☐   suspend/network_after_suspend   not supported
☐   suspend/network_before_suspend  not supported
☑   suspend/resolution_after_suspend    passed
☑   suspend/resolution_before_suspend   passed
☒   suspend/sd-insert-after-suspend failed
☐   suspend/sd-remove-after-suspend not supported
☐   suspend/sd-storage-after-suspend    not supported
☒   suspend/sdhc-insert-after-suspend   failed
☐   suspend/sdhc-remove-after-suspend   not supported
☐   suspend/sdhc-storage-after-suspend  not supported
☑   suspend/suspend_advanced    passed
☐   suspend/wireless_after_suspend  not supported
☒   suspend/wireless_before_suspend failed
```

USB tests           failed

```
☑   usb/detect  passed
☒   usb/insert  failed
☐   usb/remove  not supported
☐   usb/storage-automated   not supported
```

Uncategorised           passed

```
☑   Collect information about the CPU   passed
☑   Collect information about hardware devices (udev)   passed
☑   Collect information about hardware devices (DMI)    passed
☑   Collect information about dpkg version  passed
☑   Collect information about installed system (lsb-release)    passed
☑   Collect information about installed software packages   passed
☑   requirements    passed
☑   rtc passed
☑   sleep   passed
☑   Collect information about the running kernel    passed
```

Wireless networking tests           passed

```
☑   wireless/wireless_connection    passed
```

**Output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3802
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2112
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3806
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3820
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 0901
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Its added now.

Comment: Which kernel version? What is the output of `uname -a`?
Did this issue start happening after an update/upgrade? Was there a prior kernel version where you were not having this particular problem?

Comment: @Sary It didn't start after any updation. It started after 2,3 days from the date I received this machine.

Comment: Try the 4.10 kernel.

Comment: @Rhithwik Sathees there is no simple answer/solution to this issue. You need to debug /troubleshoot it. and or simply try installing a new kernel version and test it . https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Troubleshooting and you may get instant assistant on freenode IRC network and /join #ubuntu

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Do you have an Intel Bay Trail processor? In `terminal` show me the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -alt /var/crash` and `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema 8 GB Ram swap 20
/dev/sda1: UUID="57654bc7-f19d-447f-bd68-00f69f3ef3d6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d9fa2484-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="e5c88645-40fa-43b5-bfa9-edd257065566" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d9fa2484-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="2b574a53-dfa5-4253-9af2-1e1f8eba4d84" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d9fa2484-03"

Comment: cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

Comment: # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=57654bc7-f19d-447f-bd68-00f69f3ef3d6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /data was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=2b574a53-dfa5-4253-9af2-1e1f8eba4d84 /data           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e5c88645-40fa-43b5-bfa9-edd257065566 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: ls -alt /var/crashtotal 13384
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 Jul  4 17:47 .
-rw-r-----  1 rhithwik whoopsie   76493 Jul  4 17:32 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 rhithwik whoopsie 1598143 Jul  4 15:01 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_notify-osd.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 rhithwik whoopsie  956514 Jul  4 14:53 _usr_bin_pulseaudio.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 rhithwik whoopsie   54723 Jul  4 14:50 _usr_share_apport_apport-gtk.1000.crash

Comment: -rw-r-----  1 rhithwik whoopsie 5336508 Jul  4 14:50 _usr_bin_unity-control-center.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 rhithwik whoopsie 5663090 Jun 28 18:23 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root        4096 May  9 20:29 ..

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, it's impossible to review the information when put into comments. Can you please redo the terminal commands, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, and paste the output into the question for me? Highlight the paste and click the `code formatting`  `{}` icon to make it look nice. Then delete your last few comments with that output for me. Ping me when you're done.

Comment: Hey did u get the answer, I am still struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @NishantKashyap I got it fixed with the latest kernel update.

Answer (score 1):

**The latest kernel update solved my issue**. I forgot it to mention here!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/749145)

Comment: @Stormvirux this is the only answer. It *might* be a thank you to Pilot6 who posted [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931845/need-help-ubuntu-16-04-lts-64-bit-lenovo-machine-v310-freezes-frequently-if/950506#comment1475630_931845) but it would be a valid answer even then since there's no other *answer* suggesting this. However, "latest kernel update" is a bit vague. **Rhithwik Sathees** can you please clarify exactly what solved your problem - did you manually install a newer kernel or just run a general system update/upgrade? What's the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: I don't know why there is always a fight happening here! 
Anyways I used to run the system update but never get the issues fixed. But once my Kernel got updated to the new release my machine stopped freezing. The kernel got updated along with the system update. I didn't manually installed it. I like to give credit to @Pilot6 if there is any way.